# How to auto save compiled vue files when running npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, npm-scripts

With vue.js when setting up a project using vue CLI i can run 
`$ npm run serve`
to compile the files and start a port at `localhost:8080`

My question is what can i do so that the generated that got rendered in the page be also saved to a directory in my development machine.

Just like auto-saving and modifying so that i can be able to use the file on another project which depends on the generated files all during development

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not already creating a bundle somewhere? In some kind of `build` or `dist` folder?

Inside the `webpack` config you can check what value is used for `output`.

Comment: Certainly it did not create any hook or folder except when I run     $ npm run build          which is the command for compiling built version and this command termite after a single task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if an easier solution exists. But what i would suggest is :

1. Set `writeToDisk` option true. This will make sure your bundle written in to disk. [Link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk)
2. Then add an `after-emit hook` to the webpack pipeline:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec; // use exec to run shell command

module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [
...
    {
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('CopyOutputPlugin', (compilation) => {
          exec('command to copy output folder to desired folder');
        });
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

[child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) documentation.